# Problems Reinstalling Node js for webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am installing webpack manually. The problem seems to be that the environment variable is set incorrectly. So to reinstall nodjs, I learned and ran the code 'rm -fr /usr /usr/local/bin/{node,npm} /usr/local/lib/node_modules/'.

However, the message 'Remove-Item : Could not find a parameter that matches the parameter name 'rf''.
The path of the code should be used to fit my computer.I changed the code because I wanted to, but the same message appears.
How can I solve this?

Comment: What operating system and version? How did you install nodejs the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your folder structure, I think you are using a linux based operating system. To reinstall nodejs, you can refer to this article by digital ocean, which explains briefly on [installing and uninstalling nodejs on linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Also, if you would like remove a folder in linux or using git bash, navigate to the parent folder of node_modules, run

```
rm -rf node_module/
```

Similarly you can do it for the bin directory for {node,npm}. Also if you are looking at setting up webpack for react, you could follow this medium article by Marcos Lombog on [A Complete Webpack Setup for React](https://medium.com/swlh/a-complete-webpack-setup-for-react-e56a2edf78ae).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. And I haven't tried it yet, but I'm glad it will work.